# How to handle lots of uploads to a single server?

Tags: spring-boot, upload, jetty

I have a Digital Ocean server with Ubuntu 16.04 and 512mb of memory. It has the following technology stack:

- Nginx 1.10.0
- Java 8
- Spring Boot Application with Jetty embedded.
- The Spring Boot Application has a form that accepts file uploads.
- There is no database. The server is only to store file uploads.

What may happen if 3,000 users try to upload, each of them, a file of 1MB within a 30 minute interval?

What would be a solution for this scenario?

(Let's suppose that the average upload speed of the users is 0.8 Mbps).

Comment: You'll hit limits of your networking pretty quick.  Eg: at 3,000 users, on a 1 gigabit network connection, upload rate would be something like 40KB (if evenly spread out across all users). probably 5 minutes per user?

Comment: Thank you. Actually, the 3,000 uploads would not be exactly at the same time, but they would all occur within a 30 minute interval. I will edit the question to correct this information. Do you think network connection would be the only problem?